# Pandas groupby and custom agg lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I have a data frame and I want to aggregate a custom aggregation function.

Right now I have it like a predefined function, but I want to call it as a lambda function. Notice that the predefined function has a parameter that can be change.

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
bunch = load_boston()

y = bunch.target
X = pd.DataFrame(bunch.data, columns=bunch.feature_names)

def percentile_func(y,PERCENTILE=50):
    return np.percentile(y,PERCENTILE)

X.groupby('CHAS')['CRIM'].agg([percentile_func,'sum', 'count'])
```

Comment: `X.groupby('CHAS')['CRIM'].agg([percentile_func,'sum', 'count'])` this is working right? I guess this should work. If not what was the error traceback

Comment: Hi @Ch3steR, it works yes, but I am looking to integrate it with a lambda function, as you can read in the original question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
X.groupby('CHAS')['CRIM'].agg([lambda x: np.percentile(x, 50),'sum', 'count'])
```

Comment: yep, that I know, but then having more aggregators such as 'sum' or 'count'?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`functools.partial`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) here.

```
from functools import partial

f = partial(percentile_func,PERCENTILE=50) # you can change PERCENTILE value accordingly.

X.groupby('CHAS')['CRIM'].agg([f,'sum', 'count'])
```